# Python 2.7.5, import random is throwing error on AIX platfrom

Tags: python-2.7, aix

I am not able to  do "import random" in python 2.7.5 on AIX operating system. It throws the following exceptions.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  2 2013, 23:28:11) [C] on aix6
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/opt/freeware/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type ' + name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
```

I searched for the error it says libssl is missing can anyone tell me how to install libssl on AIX.

Comment: What version of AIX are you using?

Comment: @Colwin  I'm using AIX 6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download openssl from IBM here ->

https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/reg/download.do?source=aixbp&S_PKG=openssl

And install it like this

```
mkdir openssl.0.9.8.1103 && cd openssl.0.9.8.1103 && uncompress -c < ../openssl.0.9.8.1103.tar.Z |tar -xvf - && installp -acXYgd . openssl
```