# AIX: Python: Import Error: 'No module named _md5' when importing smtplib

Tags: python, md5, aix, smtplib

I'm trying to send emails from an AIX machine and I'm using the smptlib to do so, as that's what I've done for the other UNIX machines I'm also working on. But on AIX when I import smtplib, I get this error: 'No module named _md5'.

Python 2.7.1 on AIX 7.1

Just having either of these lines produces the error:

```py
import smtplib
import email.mime.text
```

This is the error I receive for smtplib:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/email/utils.py", line 27, in <module>
    import random
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 49, in <module>
    import hashlib as _hashlib
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 136, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 71, in __get_builtin_constructor
    import _md5
ImportError: No module named _md5
```

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the library using pip?

Comment: @blackbrandt This machine does not have pip installed and even if it did and I could use it, would that solve the issue for all users on this machine or only the one I run pip on? Because this problem is occurring in all users and I need it to work for all users.

Comment: Similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080885/aix-6-1-python-importerror-no-module-named-md5, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501983/python-2-7-5-import-random-is-throwing-error-on-aix-platfrom.  Most likely you need to install missing dependencies and rebuild/reinstall python.

Comment: @snakecharmerb What would be the best way to do this? Especially considering I'd need this to work for all users rather than just one.

Comment: @OP: where this Python came from? Has it been compiled from source?